# Getting the Java Swing 'No Drag' Cursor

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to get a reference to Swing "no Drag "Cursor ,since it is OS Specific, or maybe override it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the DragSource class which has bunch of predefined cursors.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [java.awt.Toolkit::createCustomCursor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29) if you want a cursor that is not predefined in java.awt.Cursor

```
public Cursor createCustomCursor(Image cursor,  
                                 Point hotSpot,  
                                 String name);
```

From the [Java 6 Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Creates a new custom cursor object. If the image to display is invalid, the cursor will be hidden (made completely transparent), and the hotspot will be set to (0, 0).
>   Note that multi-frame images are invalid and may cause this method to hang.